# Some PNGs are not being displayed on IE8

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8, png

I'm performing QC on an eLearning course my team has built and I'm having an issue with some PNGs that are not being displayed on IE8. Within IE9, IE11, and Chrome, the images are shown (floating right). They're not being displayed in IE8.

The weird thing is that all of the images are PNGs within this course, but only the images that are on the right hand side of the screen do not appear.

I've tried the following:

- Restarted IE8
- Looked through developer tools HTML & CSS Elements
- Researched online about the issue, but all I got were based on JPGs and transparency

Here's the image:
[screenshot for IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8fQ2.png)

Here's a snippet of the image src code.

```
<img style="position:absolute;" src="exampleimg.png" complete="complete"/>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The screenshot really doesn't help. We need to see the code. My guess is you're using some kind of CSS code that isn't compatible with IE8, but without seeing the code, that is only ever going to be a guess.